# Spring Data configuration - hibernate.properties not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I try to configure Spring Data with Hibernate in-memory database, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066939/3368498) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520461/3368498) answers:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

<!-- Configure the data source bean -->
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false">
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"></entry>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"></entry>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="models"/>
    <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
    <property name="validationMode" value="NONE"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="beans.repositories"/>
```

But over and over again I get:

> org.hibernate.cfg.Environment. HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Problem is that I don't want to specify it in `properties` file, as I used to without Spring Data I want to set it in `xml` configuration, like in answers which I base. Am I missing something? Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: Ignore the mesage. It is just an info message from hibernate... YOu probably getting one for `hibernate.cfg.xml` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right, I thought it was reason why application won't deploy to Tomcat, but problem was different. Please write your answer as normal answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is nothing more then an information message from Hibernate. You probably get another one similar to this one complaining about `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

At startup hibernate may be configured using those 2 files and hibernate logs the absence of those. Nothing more nothing less. You can simply ignore it.